# How to list all the possible binary search trees with n nodes?

Tags: c, algorithm, catalan

I want to list all the possible binary search trees. I know that the number will be the catalan number. But i want to list them also.

Let's say that I assign letters to each position of a binary search tree as shown below

[image]

Then want to list all possible trees with N nodes.  If N is 1, then the only possible tree is

```
A
```

If N is 2 then the possible trees are

```
A B
A C
```

If N is 3, the possible trees are

```
A B D
A B E
A B C
A C F
A C G
```

If N is 4, the possible trees are

```
A B D H
A B D I
... should be 12 more
```

Does anyone know a good algorithm that lists all the possible trees?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by all possible BSTs?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If N==2 there is just one tree A--B (up to isomorphism, I guess you want to count trees distinct in 'shape')

Comment: Did you think about encoding the tree as a string and reducing the problem to some string enumeration problem?

Comment: OP isn't actually looking to enumerate BST's, they are looking for all the paths in a breadth first search of maximal depth `n`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple (naive?) approach consists in recursion. A binary tree with n nodes is a root, a binary tree with `k<n` nodes and another binary tree with n-1-k nodes.

Here is the Python code corresponding to my approach. You can easily sort the output if needeed.

```
def binary_trees(n, i=0):
    if not n:
        return [[]]
    else:
        ll=[]
        for k in range(n):
            l1 = binary_trees(k, 2*i+1)
            l2 = binary_trees(n-1-k, 2*i+2)
            for j in l1:
                for l in l2:
                    ll.append([i]+j+l)
        return ll

def numbers_to_letters(l):
    return [chr(i+ord('A')) for i in l]

print [numbers_to_letters(l) for l in binary_trees(4)]
```

An improvement could probably be done via DP: compute the trees of size 1, then 2, then 3… and keep them in memory for reuse instead of re-computing those every single time.